# Filter array of objects based a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array :

```
myData: [{
   name: "",
   lastName: "",
   historicalData: [{
    data1: '',
    data2: 0,
   },
    {
    data1: '',
    data2: 30,
   }
  ]
},
{
   name: "",
   lastName: "",
   historicalData: [{
    data1: '',
    data2: 6,
   },
    {
    data1: '',
    data2: 1,
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to iterate through this array, filter it to have all the data where data2 > 2. And then sort that result by data1.

Since it is a nested array of object within an array of objects, I'm unsure of how to iterate and filter in es6.

Any suggestions ?

```
myData.filter(oneData => historicalData.data1 > 2)
```

But initially I would have to map through the historical data too. 
Expected result:

```
myData: [{
  name: "",
  lastName: "",
  historicalData: [{
    data1: '',
    data2: 30,
  }]
},{
  name: "",
  lastName: "",
    historicalData: [{
    data1: '',
    data2: 6,
  }]
}]
```

Once I have this result then I can sort accordingly.
THanks

Comment: which one of the inner array's `data2` do you want to take? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: so I need example for user 1, to loop through the inner historicalData, filter out only those with data2 > 2. And then the same for user 2.
And then sort on the result. 
Will edit it!

Comment: which array should be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build new objects and filter `historicalData`.

This solution does not mutate the original data.

```js
var data = [{ name: "", lastName: "", historicalData: [{ data1: '', data2: 0, }, { data1: '', data2: 30, }] }, { name: "", lastName: "", historicalData: [{ data1: '', data2: 6, }, { data1: '', data2: 1, }] }],
    filtered = data.map(o =>
        Object.assign({}, o, { historicalData: o.historicalData.filter(({ data2 }) => data2 > 2) }));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Much appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: After .filter(({data2}) => data2 >2) can I add a .sort( based on data1 in decreasing order ) ?

Comment: you can add a sorting at this place.

Answer (score 0):

To filter

```
 myData.map(x => x.historicalData = x.historicalData.filter(x => x.data2 >2))
```

If you want to sort as well

```
myData.map(x => x.historicalData = x.historicalData.filter(x => x.data2 >2).sort((y,z)=> y.data1.localeCompare(z.data1) ))
```

If you want to sort and filter with no mutatation

```
myData.map( m => { 
  return { 
    ...m , 
    ...{ historicalData: m.historicalData.filter(data  => data.data2 > 2) .sort((y,z)=> y.data1.localeCompare(z.data1))} 
  } 
});
```

Edit: Added localeCompare, because it's the right way to do string ordering.

Comment: that solution mutates the original data.

Comment: @NinaScholz I understand your viewpoint . But given the context of question immutability didn't seem like a concern.

Comment: @NinaScholz The ES6 documentation says that map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so).
How does it mutate? I apologize if I'm missing something, I'm a beginner , want to understand what you mean

Comment: @JeffM right, map does not mutate, but the assignment does: `x.historicalData = x.historicalData.fillter(...)`

Comment: Aah, I didn't notice that.
Thank you!!

Comment: @JeffM there is nothing inherently wrong with mutation. Unless you're passing it to some other  function.Your question didn't include such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myData = [{
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    historicalData: [{
        data1: '',
        data2: 0,

    }, {
        data1: '',
        data2: 30,

    }]
}, {
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    historicalData: [{
        data1: '',
        data2: 6,

    }, {
        data1: '',
        data2: 1,

    }]
}];

var res = myData.map( (a) => {
  a["historicalData"] = a["historicalData"].filter( (aa) => aa["data2"] > 2 );
  return a;
});

// since you were unclear about the historicalData 
// array length and how you choose set to 0
res = res.sort( (a,aa) => a["historicalData"][0].data1 - aa["historicalData"][0].data1 );
console.log(res);
```